# Check if an user exist in my database with Node and MySQL

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express, sequelize.js

This is my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-dew-iyihk?file=/server/controller/user.controller.js) in the server folder there is the back-end while the front-end is in the src one. I'm using React.js and Node.js.
Let's go to the point, I use Auth0 for authentication,I want to use Auth0's `user_id` to register users in my database in order to retrieve and update their information: e-mail, name, surname.

With Auth0 `sub` claim it's used to get the user_id. I would like to first check if the `sub` property is present in my MySQL database if true update user info with that `sub` else create new user record.

For example. johnsmith@gmail.com with sub: id1234 submit form

```
if(id1234 exist in database) {
update info;
} else {
create new user record;
}
```

Comment: among the various attempts I have made there is also `where: {sub: sub}` ... and it didn't work. On stackoverflow I have read everything, but on my own I cannot find a practical solution.

Comment: Is there any error or warning message?

Comment: Error 500 internal server " cannot updated user with sub = .(user's sub)". Look my sandbox. Maybe, it's easy to understand the problem